# java - удаление Объекта и ссылку на него из массива

Tags: java, javafx

у меня есть объект и переменная ссылкой на его экземпляр нужно из самого объекта его удалить .

а также удалить его из массива со сдвигом(без дыр) элементов.

Comment: Объясните чуть подробнее первую часть. Объект, вообще говоря, представляет из себя как раз ссылку. А объект и экземпляр (класса) – это одно и то же.

Comment: Пунктуация отсутствует

Answer (score 2):

Удаление элемента из массива со сдвигом (без дыр) элементов:

```
public static void removeElt(int [] arr, int remIndex)
{
   for (int i = remIndex ; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
   {
      arr[i] = arr[i + 1] ; 
   }
}
```

Но в этом случае у вас все элементы после удалённого переместятся выше, а последний элемент массива вам нужно обнулить, или удалить ссылку на объект, если ваш массив хранит ссылки. 
В случае же, если вы хотите получить массив с меньшей длиной элементов (например, был массив `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, а после удаления элемента "4" вы хотите получить массив `{1, 2, 3, 5}`), то используйте следующий метод:

```
public static int[] removeElt(int[] arr, int remIndex)
{
        for (int i = remIndex; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        }
        int[] newArr = new int[arr.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, newArr, 0, arr.length - 1);
        return newArr;
}
```

Этот метод возвращает новый массив. Пример его использования:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] ar = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        System.out.println("Исходный массив: ");
        for (int a : ar) {
            System.out.print(a + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\nНовый массив: ");
        int[] newArr = removeElt(ar, 3);
        for (int a : newArr) {
            System.out.print(a + " ");
        }    
}
```

И вывод:

> Исходный массив:  1 2 3 4 5
>   Новый массив:  1 2 3 5